# how to capture an image from the window mobile device using Qt?

Tags: qt, camera, windows-ce

I'm trying to capture an image from the window mobile device using Qt. Is there the APIs in Qt-wince to access the camera in the window mobile device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such API available through Qt, as Qt tries to provide the *same* API on all platforms. However, since devices differ and mobile becomes more and more important to Qt (just look at who's owning the company) there is work on a Mobility API that will expose available device specifics such as cameras, gyros, e-mail, sms, etc. For now, cameras does not seem to be implemented (at least not yet). Either way, you can look at a preview here: http://qt.nokia.com/developer/new-qt-apis .

Comment: Thanks. I just needed a full portability. Anyway, I'm going to try the native window mobile APIs.